# iOS app with real-time updates from server: Socket (using streams) or Apple Push Notification service?

Tags: ios, ios5, iostream, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to make an iOS 5 app that features real-time things coming from the server. It will only use these whilst the app is running.

To make it real-time without polling I have been evaluating two design routes:

**Creating a socket from the app to the server, and exchanging information via streams.**

- *Pros:* Relatively simple and would not involve a 3rd party.
- *Cons:* Battery life drain.
- For an overview of how this might work, check
  out this excellent tutorial:
  http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

**Using standard HTTP to communicate with the server, and with each request from the app let the server know what they are viewing. If something new is available for user, send an Apple Push Notification (with no visible alert) to let app know it can go and download new thing.**

- *Pros:* Not opening up a new TCP connection, so battery life not drained unnecessarily.
- *Cons:* Feels like a poor hack.
- The official docs on APNs http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

I think a socket would be the way to go, but before I commit to it I wanted a second opinion, as this is the first time I've made anything like this!

Comment: I would add scalability to the equation. There is a rather low limit  (a few thousands) on the number of open sockets for a given server. Short lived HTTP requests can handle many more "simultaneous" clients. I have the feeling that the APN solution will scale better.

Comment: On scalability, some servers can handle 2 million open sockets (Twitter) & others range from 24k-200k (AWS)
Twitter Blog: https://blog.whatsapp.com/196/1-million-is-so-2011?
AWS Test: https://blog.unitedheroes.net/archives/p/4633/how-many-sockets-does-aws-support-anyway/

Comment: @jon, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it really need to be "full real time"? From my point of view i would prefer http since it is already well integrated into the iOS SDK. Its easy to understand, maintain and implement and plenty of documentation is on the web. So maybe a http poll every minute or so will be enough (depending on the app and the number of users). Please consider firewalls too! Traffic to unknown ports maybe denied due to firewall policies of provider or local wifi. So if you really need realtime connectivity I guess you have to use sockets.

Comment: The spec says that it has to be genuinely real-time, but being a few seconds out is not critical. I hadn't considered firewalls and the like, that could make things rather messy.

Answer (score 5):

Sockets would be my choice. I do not know how time critical your application is, but sockets might perform better as APNs if realtime is a must.

Comment: Any links to implement it?