# Data push from server to iOS device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to send updates from server to iOS device without using APNS when application is not active (not even running in background). Any ideas regarding how can I accomplish that? One thing I want to mention is that it's not a web application to which I want to send updates. Is there any free API that could be used to meet my requirement?

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such service. If there was one, it would be a service provided by Apple as it would need to run on the system level.

If the app is still running in the background (i.e. not killed), you could use [background-app refresh](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4211) introduced in iOS7 (c.f. [this post](http://www.devfright.com/ios-7-background-app-refresh-tutorial/) for an example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tilo. Is there any service except APNS which can be used to push data from server when app is running in foreground or background?

Comment: @TejasSutar you could have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228594/ios-app-with-real-time-updates-from-server-socket-using-streams-or-apple-push?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @tilo. Seems a sensible post to me.

Comment: Yes @amar. I found one good tutorial here. http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server